# can't get a dump file using VM Option :HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError when OOM exception thrown

Tags: java, out-of-memory, dump

Firstly , I use Intelli Idea as IDE to run an application which is designed to cause an OOM Exception .
VM Option:
-Xmx20M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\aaa.hprof

Application:
    import sun.misc.Unsafe;

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
public class DirectMemoryOOM{
    private static final int _1MB=1024*1024;
    public static void main(String[]args)throws Exception{
        Field unsafeField=Unsafe.class.getDeclaredFields()[0];
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        Unsafe unsafe=(Unsafe)unsafeField.get(null);
        while(true){
            unsafe.allocateMemory(_1MB);
        }
    }
}
```

no dump file exists in directory 'C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\' after exception thrown.

Secondly , I try another way to avoid the impact of IDE ,I run this command in cmd command line:
java DirectMemoryOOM -Xmx20M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\aaa.hprof
still no dump file was created .

The log in console is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
        at DirectMemoryOOM.main(DirectMemoryOOM.java:12)
```

updated 2017/2/23 :
today I run into another jvm crash,the intelli idea console output ：

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (javaCalls.cpp:62), pid=11864, tid=13164
#  guarantee(thread->is_Java_thread()) failed: crucial check - the VM thread cannot and must not escape to Java code
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin\hs_err_pid11864.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58121', transport: 'socket'
```

I'm wondering if there's anything to do with 'Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows',Is it possible that the windows system is not configured correctly for dumping file.
I have also tried to  enable Mini-dumps through Advanced System Settings -- > Startup & Recovery -- > Settings -- > Choosing 'small memory dump'. But nothing changed.
Could anyone give some constructive advice? thx!

Comment: today I run into jvm crash :

Comment: Setting the HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag only causes heap dumps to be written if the cause of the OutOfMemoryError is that the heap has run out of space.  In other situations there's not a lot of point in dumping the heap if the heap isn't where the memory leak is.

Comment: Nice question, too. Hint: you don't put such solutions into a comment. There are two options: if you think this a very special problem; then consider deleting the question. But if you think that your question + your solution could be helpful to others; just write up your *own* answer. It is even legit to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't put the JVM option in right order. The wrong version is :java DirectMemoryOOM -Xmx20M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\aaa.hprof ,That's not correct because we need to put JVM options ahead the application class like this :java -Xmx20M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\aaa.hprof DirectMemoryOOM

Answer (score 0):

What you enabled in the system settings are minidumps in case of blue screens, i.e. when an exception happens in kernel mode. This has nothing to do with Java.

If you want minidumps for client versions of Java, add `-XX:+CreateMinidumpOnCrash` to your command line.

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers. It turns out I didn't put the JVM option in right order. The wrong version is :java DirectMemoryOOM -Xmx20M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\aaa.hprof ,That's not correct because we need to put JVM options ahead the application class like this :java -Xmx20M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=C:\Users\chao.zhang1\Desktop\aaa.hprof DirectMemoryOOM